# Can I use location-based data access to restrict users' access to certain applications in a project space?

Tags: commcare

I have 3 applications in one project space, one per country for 3 different countries. I have configured an organization structure with different locations for each country, and supervisors below each country. I have configured the location-based data access to ensure that supervisors are only able to access data and reports for their respective country, but when I log in to HQ as one of these restricted-access supervisors I still am given the option to export data/reports for all 3 countries, even though I can only access the data for one of those countries (if I export the data for a different country the export is blank). Is there any way to restrict the access to the other applications as well based on locations?

Comment: Can you confirm that you have "Full Organization Access" turned off on the role that these users are assigned to?

Comment: Yes, I configured the role of the Web User to not have access the the Full Organization Access as described in the wiki here: https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Location-Based+Data+Access+and+User+Editing+Restrictions

Comment: To clarify, are you just asking to remove the other countries from the filter options? It sounds like you're saying the data is being restricted, it's just that the options for the other countries is showing up in the filters?

Comment: Hi Nick, yeah I am asking if it is possible to filter the applications available for download by location (e.g. show only the application for the country whose location I am in) in data and report exports. The data restriction is working as expected, where if I do attempt to export data for an application whose location I do not have access to, the export is blank. Would be nice to not even give the user the option to export data for that application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot assign mobile workers or web users to applications. Using Locations to restrict access solely limits their access to data and reports.